# Eclipse PDT installation

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I have a project that's intended to use some PHP as well as Java and Javascript, so I installed the PDT PHP plug-in for Eclipse, using the Install New Software menu option. Now Eclipse agrees PDT is installed, but no PHP features like creating or editing PHP files are appearing anywhere. Is there something else I need to do to activate PDT? (I did restart Eclipse like it said I needed to.)

Comment: Have to check the output of the include modules in the help menu, to see if the plugin was loaded? Also, I believe there should be a startup log which might give you some error messages.

Comment: Eclipse 3.5.0. The Installed Software list says the plug-in is installed; is there something else I should be checking? No new error logs in the configuration directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I eventually came up with was to just install Aptana Studio, a PHP IDE based on Eclipse, whose standalone version can coexist happily with the regular Eclipse on the same machine.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your project, Configure (it's at the bottom of the list)->Add PHP Support...

After it's done, you should see a little P symbol in the project's icon.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that option! But it's not offering it either, so it's definitely a case of PDT not being active even though Eclipse says it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Just create new project using the wizard, and choose PHP one. After Eclipse will know that your project is actually based on PHP, it will show you all the features.

In case if you have existing project, just open the PHP perspective.

Comment: That's the problem, it's not offering either a new PHP project or a PHP perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I've once had a similar problem. Eclipse was running with the JRE 1.4, and it seems the JRE 1.5 or later is required to run the PDT. I switched to Java 1.6 and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this sometimes with eclipse plugins.

Have you tried uninstalling it, removing the jar and files it from eclipse/plugins and eclipse/features, then installing it again?

If you don't feel like doing that. Try installing it in a clean eclipse instance and if it works then it's just a config issue with eclipse.

You might have not installed all of the tools too.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have PHP support in eclipse project, you need to add PHPNature to the project. It's a kind of configuration paramter of eclipse project. When you craete a new PHP project using a wizard, check the .project file in a new project directory. There is a PHPNature line. Copy this line into .project of your java project.
Another solution is to separate java and php code in a different projects, each one craeted by right wizard.